# How to nail a Ph.D. interview?

Tags: phd, interview

I have been asked for an selection interview by a Professor in Australia for Ph.D. position (cancer research group). This position is really important for me so I want to give my best. Can anyone suggest some tips or share his experience of success or failure so that I can get an idea how to prepare myself.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Read a few of their papers, listen to them and ask interesting questions that show you can think critically ("hmm, that's interesting, but wouldn't Y happen if you did X?").

Answer (score 5):

Let me pretend I'm the professor. Things I will want to know:

1. What drives you? What is important in your professional life?
2. What is it about cancer research that appeals to you? The raw science? Helping humanity? Glory?
3. How big is your curiosity?
4. Why do you want to do *this* degree at *this* university?
5. Can you work hard? Where is the evidence?
6. What have you done in your previous situation that will help/hinder  you in this one?
7. Can you write? Evidence?
8. Do you follow the evidence wherever it leads?
9. Do you work well with others? How comfortable am I making you part of my group? Note that you may get to meet some of the others as part of this.
10. Have you any experience with this sort of research? If not, how fast can I predict you will catch on?
11. Do you have ideas for research for a dissertation? (Not a deal breaker if no, but possibly useful if you do.)
12. What sort of questions did you ask me in the interview? What do they say about you?
13. Other things I can't think of now but that may come up in the interview.

Take a pen and notebook so you can take quick notes if needed. Nothing elaborate or electronic. I suggest a pencil and a few index cards actually.

Note that some of these are hard to express and hard to evaluate. Some are impossible to just ask and answer. It is even counterproductive to try to directly express some of them. Showing is better than telling. Some are more important than others, but the next person has a different ranking.

I may have read your CV before the interview, but I'm pretty busy. I may want to talk to a former professor afterwards (unlikely).

But more important than all of that is to be yourself and just be comfortable with it. Don't try to force it.

---

Contrary to stereotypes, "Do you like beer?" probably won't be a consideration. Tea is acceptable.

Comment: @Dukhiatma, I forgot. Take a pen and notebook so you can take quick notes if needed. Nothing elaborate or electronic.  Good luck.